# hdiutil: command not found

Tags: gnome-terminal, command-line

I want to convert a `.iso` file to a `.img` file. So I write:

```
hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/home/antu/target.img ~/home/antu/ubuntu.iso
```

in a terminal window. It shows that:

```
hdiutil: command not found
```

So please help me?

Comment: Why would you need a `.img` file in Linux?

Comment: He wants it on OSX

Comment: see also [hdiutil on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/226439/hdiutil-on-linux)

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to AskUbuntu. `hdiutil` is a proprietary software developed by US software company Apple, it does not run on Linux.

You can use `ccd2iso` for the reverse conversion; first install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ccd2iso
```

And then run it:

```
ccd2iso ~/home/antu/target.img ~/home/antu/ubuntu.iso
```

Comment: ccd2iso can convert img -> iso, but unless I'm utterly wrong, the OP wants it the other way around.

Comment: Yes you are right, he actually states it quite clearly. The question then is: what is the usage of an `.img` in Linux?

Comment: I have no idea. I use ready-made images for installation only (Ubuntu, Raspbian, etc.).

Comment: Actually, it might be exactly that. Turn an iso to a bootable medium.

Answer (score 0):

ccd2img converts only raw img files to iso files.

There are also 'Apple Disk Image' files (Mac OS 9 and earlier) which also end with the img postfix but are completely different.