# How to change a .cdr file to a .iso file

Tags: command-line, iso

Hi I'm trying to convert a cdr to an iso. On OS X I would just use `hdiutil` but I'm new to Ubuntu so I'm not sure how to convert this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try just renaming it to ISO? [Some sources](https://superuser.com/questions/140976/how-to-burn-refit-cdr-or-dmg-in-ubuntu-or-windows) say they are the same.

Comment: ISO is an image of ISO9660 filesystem. CDR is an image of audio CD. What do you mean by converting from one into another? What files do you expect to be in the ISO9660 filesystem?

Comment: You can refer the below url for converting the cdr file to iso file: http://askubuntu.com/questions/412958/hdiutil-command-not-found